# Import project folder to gitbucket

Tags: git, webstorm, gitbucket

I have copied the repo (where i have access) to my local folder , and I want to import it to my new repo in Gitbucket , I was typing git init , git add . git commit , git push ,

but I still have the problem and i always have errors , smth like "Untracked files" , "No command done" "Up to date" , all folders in my IDE are red , and I can't import it to my new repo.I have read that i should choose some user data or urls , because previous repo wasn't created by me.Coul u help me?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "I want to import it to my new repo in Gitbucket"? Is that a server repo?

Comment: What IDE are you using?